# Blocking voltage and breakdown voltage

Tags: transistors, mosfet

Is there a difference between the blocking voltage and the.breakdown.voltage in mosfet transistor ? Or the two are the same?

Comment: Do you have an example of a data sheet for a MOSFET that has blocking voltage mentioned?

Comment: In datasheet it's always breakdown voltage but i've been reading this article http://ecee.colorado.edu/~bart/book/book/chapter7/ch7_8.htm   about vertical and lateral mosfets and it said blocking voltage so i got confused between the two are they the same or not ??

Comment: It seems that they refer to blocking voltage like most people refer to breakdown voltage.

Comment: So they are the same ?

Comment: Not quite technically I believe. There isn't one value for one MOSFET type because it depends on the gate-source voltage and temperature but if I were to put my money on something I would say that blocking voltage is referring to a voltage slightly below the worst case breakdown voltage.